# Выводятся -5-6 вместо элементов массива (то есть результата умножения). В чём моя ошибка?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;
#define usi unsigned short int
FILE* source;
void read(int* z, int max) {
    char* h = new char[max];
    cin >> h;
    z[0] = strlen(h) - 1;
    for (usi i = strlen(h), j = 0; i >= 1 && j < strlen(h); i--, j++) {
        z[i] = h[j] - '0';
    }
}
void write(int* z, int chsize) {
    for (usi i = chsize - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
        cout << z[i];
    }
}
int multp(int* f, int* m, int* r) {
    for (usi i = 1; i <= f[0]; i++) {
        for (usi j = 1; j <= m[0]; j++) {
            r[i + j - 1] += f[i] * m[j];
        }
    }
    for (usi i = 1; i < r[0]; i++) {
        r[i + 1] += (r[i] / 10);
        r[i] %= 10;
    }
    while(r[r[0] - 1] == 0) {
        r[0]--;
    }
    return r[0];
}//write the max size of 'r' array in r[0]
//multp func. returns the  REAL size of 'r' array
int main() {
    freopen_s(&source, "input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen_s(&source, "output.txt", "w", stdout);
    int a[106], b[6], rs;
    read(a, 106);
    read(b, 6);
    int nr = b[0] + a[0] + 2;
    int* rq = new int [nr];
    rq[0] = b[0] + a[0] + 1;
    rs = multp(a, b, rq);
    write(rq, rs);
    fclose(stdin);
    fclose(stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Я тестировал на коротких числах `15` и `21`, именно при этих данных выводится (-5-6).

Comment: Задайте новый вопрос, а не редактируйте код старого.

Comment: Не следует менять вопрос уже после того, как на него дан ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Включите предупреждения компилятора. Явно же сказано warning `C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'int' to 'unsigned short', possible loss of data`.